# How can I use a button to switch between the projected listview items within a textview?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a listview (for player names entered in the edittext on my loginpage). My second activity page (the actual game refers to those player names (projects the first of the list top of the screen as can be seen here: https://gyazo.com/7d8f003cc28f02343715edc66af1d819).

In order to do so, I created the following intent on the loginpage:

```
public void openActivity2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gamescreen.class);
    String s= list.get(0);
    intent.putExtra("Name1", s);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

In the game screen I refer to this as such:

```
Intent iin= getIntent();
    Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        String j =b.getString("Name1");
        playerturn.setText(j);
    }
```

Basically what I want is that when I press the button (next player) on the gamescreen that it moves from the first player name on the list to the second. As such as you keep clicking the next player button -> you move down the list.

I will need to make an onclicklistener for the click of the button, but how do I make the rest possible, with the current way I have approached it? Help much appreciated!

Comment: When you leave the log in screen, why don't you put those player names in some list or store in a db then grab them from there?

Comment: I guess I could do that, just havnt worked with a database before (so would know how to do that, and then refer to that within the next activity) Help with that would also be nice -@codemagic

Comment: https://gyazo.com/da8bb943d9568997b305687b28b889b3. This is how the loginpage looks to give more context

Comment: Setting up and using a new db is out of the scope of SO. But there are plenty of tutorials and libraries that make it very easy. If you plan on continuing in developing apps, then I strongly suggest you take some time to learn it. Also, why is this tagged with JS?

Comment: removed the javascript, just not really finding clear tutorials about databases doing exactly that which I need it to do. -@codeMagic

Comment: Plus is it entirely necessary to link it to a database for this, can i not just do it in an easier way. That when clicking the next player button it moves from position in the list?

Comment: For now, you can just create a player class and add each to a list then pull from there. I didn't look at the whole thing but basically [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423483/how-to-create-an-arraylist-class-that-can-store-multiple-objects)

Comment: Yes but Ive already created a list that grabs whatever is typed within the edittext field. This can store numerous players within the list. Made a lot clearer in the first question with the extra fotos)

Comment: Ok, then I guess I don't understand the issue if you've already got the info stored in a place you can pull it from. You store a count and move to the next index of the list to replace the name and whatever fields with the next player info

Comment: Yes exactly! and that last part is what I am having trouble with. Ive created an intent on the login page to send the info to the gamescreen activity. https://gyazo.com/7b0bfaa8f7d63ad83a653782d73fdc24. now it grabs the first in the list. But how do i make it such that every time you click the button it moves down the list

Comment: @Codemagic, how do i do this

Comment: @BorisCornelis heres the tutorial, if you want about local database. Hope it is helpful. https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/